# Should web fonts be included between head tags?

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there's a best practice of where (in what place) should I include web fonts. I mean using `<link href...>`. It looks like web fonts are included between head tags in every website I see, but the only reason I see people do this it's because fonts are being downloaded first, so you don't see that transition (flickering) when default fonts are changed to downloaded ones.

are there any more reasons why web fonts should/shouldn't be placed between head tags?

Comment: If you are not going to use them right away (i.e. apply them to sections of the page programmatically) I can see a case for loading them last, before the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quote from [Optimize the order of styles and scripts](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#PutStylesBeforeScripts) (from Google's ["Make the Web Faster" Best Practices docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/))

> stylesheets should always be specified in the head of a document for better performance, it's important, where possible, that any external JS files that must be included in the head (such as those that write to the document) follow the stylesheets, to prevent delays in download time.

Modern browsers wait with any sort of rendering until the entire `<head>` section is retrieved (including the files linked within it). So it would be nice to add 
as little things as you can to this section.

So you would better add it before any `<script>` in the `<head>` section of your document.

There are more considerations, [Yahoo's list of optimizations](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is well worth your time to read through. [Google has some good advice](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html) as well.